# High PIDs for httpd in directadmin

Tags: apache

I installed and configured Direct Admin custom build 3 and I found high PIDs for `httpd` process.

Here is a picture of the services and the processes

[image]

I searched and found this might be because of SSL certificates. I checked and disabled ssl certificates for the entire domain but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem fixed!

there was a problem in `dns` management , 2 same A record was added to different `ips`

Answer (score 0):

There is option called `StartServers` for prefork module. This controls number of httpd processes to be launched.

While using directadmin, you can set required value for `StartServers` in `ap2/conf/extra/httpd-mpm.conf` configuration file.